# XSLT - Dynamic nesting of elements

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working on a stylesheet that outputs HTML from XML inputs. I have to generate different nesting levels in the output file according to the position of a list of elements in the input. For instance, NEWS[1] and NEWS[2] should be nested under same element as well as NEWS[3] and NEWS[4].

This is an example of XML input:

```
<NEWS_LIST>
    <NEWS>
        <TITLE>Title of the notice #1</TILE>
        <IMG_URL>http://media/image_1.png</IMG_URL>
    </NEWS>
    <NEWS>
        <TITLE>Title of the notice #2</TILE>
        <IMG_URL>http://media/image_2.png</IMG_URL>
    </NEWS>
    <NEWS>
        <TITLE>Title of the notice #3</TILE>
        <IMG_URL>http://media/image_3.png</IMG_URL>
    </NEWS>
    <NEWS>
        <TITLE>Title of the notice #4</TILE>
        <IMG_URL>http://media/image_4.png</IMG_URL>
    </NEWS>
</NEWS_LIST>
```

Desired HTML output:

```
<div class="middle>
    <div class="unit 1">
        <div class="unit 2">
            <img src="http://media/image_1.png"/>
            <p>Title of the notice #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="unit 2">
            <img src="http://media/image_2.png"/>
            <p>Title of the notice #2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="unit 1">
        <div class="unit 2">
            <img src="http://media/image_3.png"/>
            <p>Title of the notice #3</p>
        </div>
        </div class="unit 2">
            <img src="http://media/image_4.png"/>
            <p>Title of the notice #4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using XSLT position() function to select elements and  to output files but I don't know how to nest childs. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you browse the `NEWS` nodes in two phases:

- 1. First phase: Match all the *odd* position nodes:

     `<xsl:apply-templates select="NEWS[(position() mod 2)=1]" mode="unit1"/>`

  ...and for each one, apply the second phase to it and to the next one:

  `<xsl:template match="NEWS" mode="unit1">
  <div class="unit 1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="unit2"></xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::NEWS[1]" mode="unit2"/>
  </ div>
  </xsl:template>`
- 2. Second phase: Print each node processed.

     `<xsl:template match="NEWS" mode="unit2">
     <div class="unit 2">
         <img src="{IMG_URL}" />
         <p><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></p>
     </ div>
     </xsl:template>`

Note that there are two templates matching `NEWS`, but they differ in the `mode` (which is proper for each *phase*).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the 'following-sibling' expression. Thank you very much, your answer was really helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. The `following-sibling` is one of the XPath _axes_: The directions in which an expression may be followed: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes